# How to destructure and initializing missing, nested fields in the same expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I've been trying to figure out if nested ES6 destructuring supports this functionality. I would like to assign `a` as an empty object if it doesn't exist, and subsequently assign it's property name `b` to a scope variable `b`.

```
var {
  a = {},
  a: {
    b = 2,
  },
} = {};

VM40:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `b` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at <anonymous>:6:5
```

It seems I can't really nest destructuring without assuming the objects format. The following works, but I'm looking for a more concise method where you can easily see the nested layout of the original object.

```
var {
  a = {},
} = {};

var {
  b = 2,
} = a;

// works as expected
// starts to look crazy when 'forking' branches that may or may not exist
```

Comment: Do you actually want a variable named `a` to use, or `b` only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for

```
var {
  a: {
    b = 2,
  } = {},
//  ^^^^
} = {};
```

The default initialiser comes after the target (which is the inner destructuring expression here). If you are looking to initialise both the variables `a` and `b`, there's not much else you can do other than having two assignments:

```
var {
  a = {},
} = {},
{
  b = 2,
} = a;
```

This might look cleaner with two `var` declarations like you did. If you insist on doing it in one nested expression, you can do

```
var {
  a = {}, // short for `a: a = {}`
  a: {
    b = 2,
  } = a, // use either `a` or another empty object as the default
} = {};
```

but I consider that pretty unreadable.

Comment: is it possible to cast `a` at the same time? after running this, `a` is not defined

Comment: yea man, it seems futile, I was hoping there's a way to initialize a deep object (tree) at the same time as casting properties to scope variables. whether or not they existed in the original, i was hoping to have a resultant, unfragmented object that's consistent with the child var values

Comment: `var {
  a: a = {
    b: b = 2,
  },
  a: {
    b: b = 2,
  } = a,
} = {
  a: {
    b: 3,
  },
};` works the same as 
`var {
  a: a = {
    b: b = 2,
  },
  a: {
    b: b = 2,
  } = a,
} = {};`

Comment: @neaumusic You don't want to use `{ b: b = 2, }` with the assignment to `b` in the default value object literal. Just `var { a: a = {b: 3}, a: { b = 2 } = a } = { a: { b: 1 } };` (if `.a.b` exists, `b` is 1 (here), if only `.a` exists it becomes 2, if the object is completely empty then `b` becomes 3).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bergi's answer, this is what I was ultimately going for.

The part I missed was that you can initialize a variable and use the variable within the same overall destructure "`} = a,`"

```
(() => { 
  var {
    a: a = {
      b: {
        c: 3,
      },
    }, // if a exists, cast to a, otherwise initialize
    a: {
      b: b = {
        c: 3,
      }, // if b exists, cast to b, otherwise initialize
      b: {
        c: c = 3, // if c exists, cast to c, otherwise initialize
      } = b,
    } = a,
  } = {
    a: {
      foo: 'bar', // passes through bc spread operator, can't easily delete afaik
    },
  }; // could be destructured from any form of an object

  return {
    a: {
      ...a,
      b: {
        ...b,
        c: c,
      },
    },
  };
})();
```